# Will a 4K external monitor create a sharper display when connected to my MacBook Pro

Tags: display, displayport, resolution

I recently connected my MacBook Pro Retina, 15-inch, Late 2013 running 10.12.6 to the Asus PB238Q 23-inch via the mini display cable to VGA cable. The max resolution of the external monitor is 1920 x 1080.

The external display is not as crisp as my retina display, is this due to how I am connecting the monitor, or is it simply because I don't have enough pixels on my external monitor to display it with the same level of sharpness?

If I was to purchase a 4k monitor would this solve the problem?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Probably a little of both - you've got a digital to analog conversion (mini-DP to VGA) which is going to cause some loss, and the Asus display is ~96 PPI vs. the MacBooks ~220 PPI.  4K display with mini DP to DP would definitely help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "sharpness" of a display is defined by its pixel density and measured in ppi (pixels per inch). So it is the combination of size and resolution that makes a display appear sharp.
Unless the 4K monitor is extremely large the pixel density will be higher then on your 1920 x 1080 pixel display.

You can check compatibility on [Using 4K displays, 5K displays, and Ultra HD TVs with your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206587).

In your case, your Late 2013 MacBook Pro 15" supports 4K displays. However you also have to use a cable that supports the resolution accordingly. For example:

HDMI:

- 3840 x 2160 at 30Hz
- 4096 x 2160 at 24Hz